# How to add a hyperlink in Div and make it clickable?

Tags: html, css

how do i add a link to a Div like below and make it clickable? I am using an image for the background of the Div and i want to make the whole image clickable.

```
<div class="grid__item-wrap">
<div class="grid__item" style="background-image: url(img/5.jpg)">
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried below two methods but none of them worked out for me.

**Method 1:**

```
<div class="grid__item-wrap">
<div class="grid__item" style="background-image: url(img/1.jpg)">
<div class="frame__links">
<a style="pointer-events: auto" class="frame__links" href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<div class="grid__item-wrap">
<div class="grid__item" href="https://www.google.com/" style="background-image: url(img/4.jpg); pointer-events: auto;">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that by using `onclick="window.location.href` as you wanna redirect when you click on `div`

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;background-image: url(img/4.jpg)" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';">Hello</div>
```

**Method-2:** You can wrap your `div` inside `a` tag and give `background-image` for the `div` and `href` path to `a` tag.

Comment: he wants css and html only

Comment: do i have to add script for this too? or it will simply work like this?

Comment: @HamzaAnsari No need to add any script. It will work

Comment: @HamzaAnsari Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. Happy coding:)

Comment: @SaiManoj Thanks it worked for me, i'll accept you answer in 4 minutes!

Comment: Glad that i could help you :) @HamzaAnsari

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the div you wanted clickable inside `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <div class="grid__item-wrap">
        <div class="grid__item" style="background-image: url(img/5.jpg)">
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Change the <div class="grid__item"...> to <img src="img/5.jpg"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
.frame__links {
     display:block;
     height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid__item {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
  <div class="grid__item-wrap">
    <div class="grid__item">
      click here
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `div` element that you want to inside the a `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the div inside an `<a>` tag should work. And style it in CSS with the cursor property to show that it is clickable.